# how to handle DPR in diameter and when DPR will send? is any condition for sending DPR?

Tags: java, tcp, sctp, diameter-protocol

I want to know that: how to send DPR in diameter. Is there any particular condition for sending DPR? In my code I have already done DWR & DWA and CEA & CER. DPR is sent after CER or before CEA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DPR means a Diameter peer wants to disconnect from a Diameter peer its currently connected to.

Its all on the base RFC. I suggest to read every command you want to implement:

[rfc 6733](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6733#section-5.4):

> 5.4.  Disconnecting Peer Connections

> When a Diameter node disconnects one of its transport connections,
> its peer cannot know the reason for the disconnect and will most
> likely assume that a connectivity problem occurred or that the peer
> has rebooted.  In these cases, the peer may periodically attempt to
> reconnect, as stated in Section 2.1.  In the event that the
> disconnect was a result of either a shortage of internal resources or
> simply that the node in question has no intentions of forwarding any
> Diameter messages to the peer in the foreseeable future, a periodic
> connection request would not be welcomed.  The Disconnection-Reason
> AVP contains the reason the Diameter node issued the Disconnect-Peer-
> Request message.

> The Disconnect-Peer-Request message is used by a Diameter node to
> inform its peer of its intent to disconnect the transport layer and
> that the peer shouldn't reconnect unless it has a valid reason to do
> so (e.g., message to be forwarded).  Upon receipt of the message, the
> Disconnect-Peer-Answer message is returned, which SHOULD contain an
> error if messages have recently been forwarded, and are likely in
> flight, which would otherwise cause a race condition.

> The receiver of the Disconnect-Peer-Answer message initiates the
> transport disconnect.  The sender of the Disconnect-Peer-Answer
> message should be able to detect the transport closure and clean up
> the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Or explained in short: if you cut the TCP/SCTP connection without sending DPR, the other side will assume that there was a networking issue and will, most likely, attempt to reconnect immediately.

With DPR, in the Disconnect-Cause AVP you can specify the reason:

- REBOOTING(0) - you may reconnect, but sounds like later
- BUSY(1) - you should not reconnect, this node is overloaded, try to find alternatives
- DO_NOT_WANT_TO_TALK_TO_YOU(2) - if you try to reconnect, it will be rejected (the peer connection was most likely unconfigured)

(The somehow still open questions: is the DPA is really needed, how long should the other side wait for it, etc.)